# `>=` condition not working in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have written code to check the textarea scroll down. Mcode working fine in FF4 but not in Chrome.

```
 var psconsole = $('#tos');
            //psconsole.scrollTop(psconsole[0].scrollHeight - psconsole.height());
            psconsole.scroll(function(){
            var acutalHight = psconsole[0].scrollHeight - psconsole.height();
            var scrolHight = psconsole[0].scrollTop ;
            console.log("scrolHight:" + scrolHight + "<<<<>>>>>"+ "acutalHight:" +acutalHight);
                    if(scrolHight+10 >= acutalHight){

                        $("#btnSignup").attr("disabled", false);
                    }else{

                        $("#btnSignup").attr("disabled", true);
                    }                       


            });
```

if condition `>=` not working in Chrome

while scrolled the scrolHight value and acutalHeight value as below

```
scrolHight:2627<<<<>>>>>acutalHight:2696
scrolHight:2639<<<<>>>>>acutalHight:2696
scrolHight:2651<<<<>>>>>acutalHight:2696
scrolHight:2675<<<<>>>>>acutalHight:2696
scrolHight:2687<<<<>>>>>acutalHight:2696
scrolHight:2696<<<<>>>>>acutalHight:2696
```

in chrome I am getting scroll value as below

```
doSignUp:179scrolHight:1862<<<<>>>>>acutalHight:2686
doSignUp:179scrolHight:2128<<<<>>>>>acutalHight:2686
doSignUp:179scrolHight:2394<<<<>>>>>acutalHight:2686
doSignUp:179scrolHight:2660<<<<>>>>>acutalHight:2686
doSignUp:179scrolHight:2670<<<<>>>>>acutalHight:2686
doSignUp:179scrolHight:2682<<<<>>>>>acutalHight:2686
```

I think problem is chrome not calculating the textarea height upto the end textarea has some drag icon in end for 4px.... chrome not calculate those but FF4 did. And its not working in IE9 too

Comment: Have you tried using the chrome inspector for debugging? Make sure no errors are occurring? (I'm also assuming it's not the variable names, as (though misspelled) they are consistent.)

Comment: Can you please tell me the value of scrolHight and acutalHight before that condition, because it could very well be that they aren't numerical i.e. contain "px" or something else, or even auto, % or something like that.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `.prop()` instead of `.attr()` or, if you have an old jQuery version not supporting `.prop()`, use `.removeAttr('disabled')` to re-enable the button..

Oh, and you have typos in your var names - they should be `scrollHeight` and `actualHeight`.

Comment: Indeed use `.prop()`, though `.attr()` was only deprecated since jQuery 1.6.

Comment: I think you mean since 1.6.1 - 1.6 did not allow setting props with `.attr()`

Answer (score 0):

The logic comparision `>=` most certainly does work in Chrome.

In the given example, `scrolHight` is *less than* `acutalHight` when evaluated in Chrome. Without further code nor details of where and how these variables are being set it is not possible to say why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

check to see if there are any floating point errors.
Or check if the indeed can be compared at all... i.e if they are defined and is number